# Most significant technical challenges in AI Safety for government?

Tags: llm, prompt-design, gpt, stable-diffusion, fine-tuning

I was thinking about the key technical aspects of implementing LLMs within a government context. It's clearly a very different operating model to the large (and small) tech firms that are leading on frontier models, and they also have different constraints.

For example, while some amount of false positives (hallucinations) are acceptable in a private sector context, it becomes legally dicey for a government to operate an LLM that returns false information (even if it's rare) about benefits entitlement, tax obligations, rights, etc.

I'm curious to hear what the people in this forum think? Are there unique technical challenges that government faces when implementing GenAI?